# Plagiarism Checker

Tags: publications, plagiarism

My first research paper is due tomorrow and my university does not seem provide students access to Turnitin. There are numerous other plagiarism checkers online but none seem to be reliable.

Are there any services that I can use that is as reliable as Turitin?

Comment: Why would you want to perform a plagiarsm check on your own paper? You should know whether you plagiarised or not.

Comment: If the university allowed students to use Turnitin, then students who *had* plagerised would find it easy to hide evidence of their wrongdoing.

Comment: My paper is based on my own algorithm which I've developed, I mostly want to check for plagiarism in the introduction and other places where I've explained certain concepts and referenced other work.

Comment: How do you know _none seem to be reliable_?

Comment: Turnitin will almost always give you a non-zero plagerism percentage; your supervisor/professor/marker will be able to glance through the output and see whether you've actually breached academic integrity or if its a false positive. In short, if you're confident you haven't plagerised, don't worry about it

Comment: You may also be interested in the answers to [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29723/7734).

Comment: The best plagiarism checker is a clean conscience that you actually wrote every word yourself.

Comment: I wrote a paper about calculating the gas compressibility factor of gases, and Turnitin flagged my references in its similarity detection. According to Turnitin a truly original paper would not reference other work.