# Can I replicate Thesis using a different subject of study?

Tags: phd, thesis, plagiarism

Let’s say there is this dissertation:

> The impact of interest rate on economic growth in country X

Can I write my dissertation about:

> The impact of interest rate on economic growth in country Y

Comment: This seems far too shallow of a contribution for a dissertation. What if you generalized their approach such that it could be applied to *any* country? That might be interesting. Talk to your advisor about it!

Comment: _can I follow the same chapters the previous author did?_ That seems like a really strange thing to do. Surely the more meaningful thing to do is follow the same methodology.

Comment: Also, what is your goal? Replicating previous work on a different country is unlikely to suffice for a PhD thesis, but it might form part of your PhD or be a Masters thesis.

Comment: *Will it be detected by Turnitin?* – [This is not he question you should ask.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29723/7734)

Comment: It is plagiarism only if you do it without citing that previous dissertation.

Answer (score 3):

It is not (necessarily) plagiarism (unless you actually copy parts, or merely rewrite the previous thesis), but it would make a pretty boring thesis. A PhD should add something new to a field; investigating the same thing in a different group/country would probably not be enough. Therefore, you can, probably, not write your thesis about it (i.e. the thesis committee/advisor/... would probably not accept it as being sufficient for a PhD thesis).

Unless, that is, you add something interesting. One possibility could be (though keep in mind that I am in a very different field) to say that:

> According to previous work, the effect of foo is bar, as shown by studies in Country X. Country X is a dictatorship/christian/... country. There are reasons A, B and C to suggest that foo⇒bar has been observed because of Country X being a ... country. According to our theory, in a democratic/pastafarian/... country the effect of foo should be buu, not bar. We test our theory in Country Y, which has such a system. Furthermore we show that the effect foo depends on [country property] by doing some more studies.