# Do researchers use plagiarism tools before sending their manuscripts to the publishers?

Tags: publications, plagiarism

Do student researchers use plagiarism tools before sending their manuscripts to the publishers? If they do, do they spend money on this type of software from their own pockets?

If someone doesn't want to spend money from their own pocket, can they approach  their P.I. or the faculty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the acceptable similarity in a mathematics PhD dissertation when checking by Turnitin?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29723/what-is-the-acceptable-similarity-in-a-mathematics-phd-dissertation-when-checkin)

Comment: There's a bunch of questions like this, and the answer to all of them is that you should be able to detect plagiarism yourself if you wrote the document, so the software is pointless.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This assumes you trust your co-authors 100%.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If you are the coauthor who did not write the document, you should know enough about it to be able to tell if it was plagiarized.  If you do not know that much, you have not earned coauthorship, in my view.

Answer (score 15):

If you wrote your manuscript yourself and did not plagiarise, then you probably won't need to check it using a plagiarism detection software?  The purpose of this software is to detect potential plagiarism in the work submitted by someone else. As a PI, if my student or postdoc asked me to pay for them to check their own writing for plagiarism, it would make me somewhat concerned.

Comment: I did some paraphrasing. Now, I am concerned that if they are good enough.

Comment: You can show the original text and your paraphrased writing to your adviser/PI and ask what they think about it.

Comment: @user366312 Plagiarism is not about insufficient paraphrasing, it is about not giving credit where credit is due: when you read something somewhere and pass it as your own. Paraphrasing exists to present a coherent story and has actually little to do with plagiarism aside from the easiest way to *detect* it.